# Hibernate Post-Insert Event Unexpected Behavior

Tags: hibernate, events, exception, insert

I am working with Hibernate 3.5.6 trying to make use of the Post-Insert event listener. I encountered a behavior which seems inconsistent with the notion of post processing an event. I go to commit an object to the DB which causes the session to be flushed and the post-insert event to be triggered. After the post-insert event is triggered, it does some processing and eventually throws an error which then travels all the way back to the original transaction. It is here that the error is caught. I am unable to rollback the transaction from this point and there is no entry in the DB. I have confirmed my code performs as expected if the post-insert event listener is removed.

Is it the expected behavior of a post-anything event in hibernate to affect the original transaction? My understanding is that a post event should be wholly independent of the original transaction.

Please see code segments and stack trace below.

**STACK TRACE**

```
at ems.server.domain.IpeManager.getCrcMessage(IpeManager.java:113) ~[bin/:na]
at ems.shared.hibernateEvents.PostInsertListener.onPostInsert(PostInsertListener.java:34) [bin/:na]
at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.postInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:148) [hibernate3.jar:3.5.6-Final]
at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:127) [hibernate3.jar:3.5.6-Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:267) [hibernate3.jar:3.5.6-Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:259) [hibernate3.jar:3.5.6-Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:178) [hibernate3.jar:3.5.6-Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321) [hibernate3.jar:3.5.6-Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51) [hibernate3.jar:3.5.6-Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206) [hibernate3.jar:3.5.6-Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:375) [hibernate3.jar:3.5.6-Final]
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137) [hibernate3.jar:3.5.6-Final]
at ems.server.database.dao.Dao.saveOrUpdate(Dao.java:30) [bin/:na]
at ems.server.database.dao.IpeComponentDao.insertComponent(IpeComponentDao.java:29) [bin/:na]
at ems.server.domain.NetworkManager.insertIpeConfig(NetworkManager.java:2876) [bin/:na]
```

**DAO CLASS**

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try {
       tx = session.beginTransaction();
       session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
       tx.commit();
       return obj;
} catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
       if (tx != null)
              tx.rollback();
       throw e;
} catch (HibernateException he) {
       if (tx != null)
              tx.rollback();
       throw new HibernateException("Could not save object of class " + obj.getClass().getName(), he);
}
```

**Hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<event type="post-insert">
        <listener class="ems.shared.hibernateEvents.PostInsertListener"/>
</event>
```

**PostInsertListener Class**

```
package ems.shared.hibernateEvents;

import java.util.*;

import org.hibernate.event.PostInsertEvent;
import org.hibernate.event.PostInsertEventListener;

public class PostInsertListener implements PostInsertEventListener{

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

       public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event)  {
          //DO SOME PROCESSING HERE
       }      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but on looking into the same problem I found a suggested solution here:

[Hibernate Event Listeners - Rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149870/hibernate-event-listeners-rollback)

Hope it helps someone in the future.

Margaret

Comment: Thanks --- I eventually came to the same conclusion that utilizing getCurrentSession() was the problem. Explicit session management solved the problem for me (i.e. openSession() and closeSession())